CoInitializeEx Success but OleSetClipboard faild in a DLL in a UI thread
I do this at the beginning of a UI thread function. This means that after this line a Window is created with CreateWindow and the wndproc has his own message loop:
    HRESULT hrComResult = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hrComResult)) {
    // Proceed with COM operations, as initialization was successful or already done
    auto hr = OleSetClipboard(nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // "Handle OleSetClipboard failure"
    }
}

The result from CoInitializeEx is S_OK but the OleSetClipboard says that "CoInitialize has not been called" 0x800401f0.
In VS2022 I see in the Threads output window that the code is executed from the Worker Thread.
What can we do to fix or anlyze it?
I tried the code above in a Console App with the same result.
int main()
{
    HRESULT hrComResult = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hrComResult)) {
        std::cerr << "CoInitializeEx failed with HRESULT: " << std::hex << hrComResult << "\n";
        return FALSE;
    }

    HRESULT hr = OleSetClipboard(nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cerr << "OleSetClipboard failed with HRESULT: " << std::hex << hr << "\n";
        CoUninitialize(); // Clean up COM library
        return FALSE;
    }

}


Clipboard requires OleInitialize()
